# JPA @PreUpdate is called for all child objects while adding new child object to parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a one to many relationship between the parent and the child.
Below is the code snippet of the relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId",referencedColumnName="parentId")
    private Set<Child> child = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Also, I am using the `@PreUpdate` and `@PrePersist` for performing some audit operation on the entity before I am trying to save and update the objects.

The `@PrePresist` looks to work just fine. It is called before I am trying to persist a new object in the data store as mentioned in the docs.

I am facing issues while using `@PreUpdate`. If the parent has multiple childrens and when we try to add another child to it `entityManager.merge(parent)`. `@PrePresist` is getting called correctly as we are inserting a new child record but it's also calling the `@PreUpdate` annotated method for all the childs that are already present in the parent though nothing has changed in any of the child object. It should have not called the `PreUpdate` for all the childrens as nothing is updated in them.

Does anyone have any clue on why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

That is by design actually. The reason for invoking `PreUpdate` on all children is that in this case hibernate first removes all children and then reinserts them. This behaviour is described in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-unidirectional.

You have this problem because in this case parent owns the association. That means that when parent is saved the association between parent and children is updated in database. There is no way to do that other then delete all children and reinsert them.

One might propose the solution where hibernate tracks what changes were done to the collection and just inserts records that were added and removes the entries that were deleted. While this seems to be a solution but it will not work if the association was changed in the database already.

The essence of the problem is that when client invokes `parent.save` it expects that after save completes database will contain the records for children associated with `parent` that were in the `children` collection when `save` was invoked.

If hibernate just tracks additions and removals and only executes those operations the following scenario will cause a problem.

Let's assume that parent is associated with two children already:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.children(asSet(child1, child2));
parent.save();
```

Then two clients read parent state from the database simultaneously.

Client 1:

```
Parent parent = dao.getParent(parentId);
```

Client 2:

```
Parent parent = dao.getParent(parentId);
```

The first client adds a child and saves:

```
parent.children().add(child3);
parent.save();
```

So far so good. But the second client still has the version of the parent that has only `child1` and `child2`. If that client for example deletes `child1` and saves:

```
parent.children().remove(child1);
parent.save();
```

It expects that parent contains now only `child2` (as that's what `children` collection contained at the moment of saving). But if we are using the tracking implementation and such removal only issues something like:

```
DELETE FROM child where parent_id = <parent_id> and id = <child1_id>
```

then there will be still two records associated with that parent - `child2` and `child3`.

Hope that's makes sense and explains why hibernates removes all children and reinserts them.

To solve your issue you need to use [bidirectional](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional) `OneToMany` association so that child side of the association manages it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Roman, Just one single doubt here. I did try to check the application logs by enabling showsql=true but I don’t see any delete queries while updating the child records. I can only see update queries for all the child records.